# Будет ли функция FastPos работать быстрее Pos?

Tags: delphi

```
function FastPos(SubStr: char; FullStr: string): integer;
var i: integer;
begin
 FastPos := 0;
   for i:=1 to length(FullStr) do
     if FullStr[i] = SubStr then begin
       FastPos := i;
       break;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: А померять слабо?
Но есть один момент, нельзя сравнивать Вашу FastPos и стандартную Pos. Стандартная ищет строку в другой, а Ваша - символ... Так что...

Comment: Слабо.. Иначе не писал бы суда..

Comment: GetTickCount Вам в помощь.

    var t:cardinal;
        i:integer;
        r:integer; // кол-во попыток
    begin
      t := gettickcount();
      for i := 1 to r do begin
        // тут Ваш код
      end;
      t := GetTickCount - t;
      ShowMessage('Выполнение заняло ' + inttostr(t) + 'ms, выполнение одной иттерации '+floattostr(t/r) + ' ms');
    end;

Грубо, но для тестов хватит. Увеличьте кол-во циклов, если время выполнения будет меньше 50-100 мс. Оптимально - несколько секунд (хотя это очень индивидуально).

Comment: Спасибо. Интересно, опробовал, работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по всему не быстрее. Изучая ассемблерный код твоей функции и функции pos, можно сделать заключение, что ее код более производительный, так как в основном использует регистры процессора, а не ячейки памяти, как в твоей. Если не прав поправте.

Код Pos 
procedure       _Pos{ substr : ShortString; s : ShortString ) : Integer};
asm
{     ->EAX     Pointer to substr               }
{       EDX     Pointer to string               }
{     <-EAX     Position of substr in s or 0    }

```
    PUSH    EBX
    PUSH    ESI
    PUSH    EDI

    MOV     ESI,EAX { Point ESI to substr           }
    MOV     EDI,EDX { Point EDI to s                }

    XOR     ECX,ECX { ECX = Length(s)               }
    MOV     CL,[EDI]
    INC     EDI             { Point EDI to first char of s  }

    PUSH    EDI             { remember s position to calculate index        }

    XOR     EDX,EDX { EDX = Length(substr)          }
    MOV     DL,[ESI]
    INC     ESI             { Point ESI to first char of substr     }

    DEC     EDX             { EDX = Length(substr) - 1              }
    JS      @@fail  { < 0 ? return 0                        }
    MOV     AL,[ESI]        { AL = first char of substr             }
    INC     ESI             { Point ESI to 2'nd char of substr      }

    SUB     ECX,EDX { #positions in s to look at    }
                    { = Length(s) - Length(substr) + 1      }
    JLE     @@fail
```

@@loop:
        REPNE   SCASB
        JNE     @@fail
        MOV     EBX,ECX { save outer loop counter               }
        PUSH    ESI             { save outer loop substr pointer        }
        PUSH    EDI             { save outer loop s pointer             }

```
    MOV     ECX,EDX
    REPE    CMPSB
    POP     EDI             { restore outer loop s pointer  }
    POP     ESI             { restore outer loop substr pointer     }
    JE      @@found
    MOV     ECX,EBX { restore outer loop counter    }
    JMP     @@loop
```

@@fail:
        POP     EDX             { get rid of saved s pointer    }
        XOR     EAX,EAX
        JMP     @@exit

@@found:
        POP     EDX             { restore pointer to first char of s    }
        MOV     EAX,EDI { EDI points of char after match        }
        SUB     EAX,EDX { the difference is the correct index   }
@@exit:
        POP     EDI
        POP     ESI
        POP     EBX
end;

И код твоей функции:

004520E3 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]

004520E6 E82120FBFF       call @LStrLen

004520EB 8BD0             mov edx,eax

004520ED 85D2             test edx,edx

004520EF 7E16             jle +$16

004520F1 B801000000       mov eax,$00000001

004520F6 8B4DFC           mov ecx,[ebp-$04]

004520F9 3A5C01FF         cmp bl,[ecx+eax-$01]

004520FD 7504             jnz +$04

004520FF 8BF0             mov esi,eax

00452101 EB04             jmp +$04

00452103 40               inc eax

00452104 4A               dec edx

00452105 75EF             jnz -$11

00452107 33C0             xor eax,eax

00452109 5A               pop edx

0045210A 59               pop ecx

0045210B 59               pop ecx

0045210C 648910           mov fs:[eax],edx

0045210F 6824214500       push $00452124

00452114 8D45FC           lea eax,[ebp-$04]

00452117 E8301DFBFF       call @LStrClr

0045211C C3               ret

0045211D E92E17FBFF       jmp @HandleFinally

00452122 EBF0             jmp -$10

00452124 8BC6             mov eax,esi

00452126 5E               pop esi

00452127 5B               pop ebx

00452128 59               pop ecx

00452129 5D               pop ebp

0045212A C3               ret

Comment: моя функция имеет на асме 31 строку-команд.. стандартная содержит 43 таких строки..

или же тут берут быстротой регистры регистры, нежели ячейки памяти?

Answer (score 0):

Код Pos либо такой же, либо лучше. Значит ваша функция не будет работать быстрее.

Comment: Так такой же или лучше? Или хуже? о_О

Comment: Согласен, написать более быстрый аналог функции из стандартной библиоти, надо постараться...

Comment: Ну вопрос был будет ли ваша функция быстрее. Код pos явно не хуже, там не индусы кодят. Значит ваш код не будет работать быстрее, значит нет смысла его использовать. Поглядите что за код в System.pas и сюда кинте, у меня нет под рукой делфи.